# SSL in Play Framework causes 'General SSLEngine prob.' (nginx)

Tags: ssl, nginx, playframework

I have a server structure of 2 servers: One is the main server with the content and the other is a Scala server with Play running, doing the user management including social login (fb, tw, g+). Both server use the same wildcard SSL cert.

I recently switched on the main server from Apache to nginx and for some reason, the Scala server complains about the SSL mismatch (which has never been a problem before under Apache).

When I try to login, I get the following error from Play:

```
[error] s.c.ProviderController - Unable to log user in. An exception was thrown
java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem to https://www.example.com/login/corsValid
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:103) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:427) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:413) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:380) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1417) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1293) ~[netty.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1290) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:513) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:793) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:761) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1225) ~[netty.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1694) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:278) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:283) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:138) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
```

I traced down the problem and found out that the `application.conf` needs to have correct parameters for the SSL certs being used. I created a JKS and P12 cert and included it in the conf file, but I still get this error. (Maybe wrong path? Tried that as well...)

```
ws.ssl {
  trustManager = {
    stores = [
      { path: "ssl.jks" }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, when I add `ws.acceptAnyCertificate=true` instead everything is fine, but this is clearly a security vulnerability and nothing I wanna do.

Why is installing an SSL cert such a pain in Play?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Play mainly an application framework, not a web server.

Our play apps always communicate unsecured with Nginx web server (in DMZ), SSL/TLS communication terminated with Nginx. With this design, you can load balance if your Play app is stateless.

Then if you want, forward everything in custom http headers from Nginx to backend (eg. client certification) for validation.

```
proxy_set_header APP-Cert-Verified $ssl_client_verify;
proxy_set_header APP-Client-Cert $ssl_client_cert;
proxy_set_header APP-Client-Cert-DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
```

You can find this in the official documentation as well:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/HTTPServer#Set-up-with-nginx.

Bonus: if certification expires you can change certs in nginx more easily, than restart your Play app.